# Replace every letter in string method java

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have to create a java method which is provided with a string input and it must return a string.

The method must take the input string and replace every letter in that string with another letter from a table.

For instance the table is :

```
Input | Output
 a     | n
 c     | H
 h     | B
 @     | q
```

and if the input is "aahh@" then the output must be "nnBBq"

Please assist with this java method thanks. And how can the table be stored efficiently in java. The real table is much longer i.e. 35 terms. thanks

i have tried this...

```
public String func(String s){
   for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
      //what to do?
   }
}
```

Regards,
Gayle

Comment: Are you asking for homework answers ? ;)

Comment: You can use hash map as a table and iterate over the string to replace

Comment: There are many not very complicated ways to achieve that. We can help you more forward but we need to know what is stopping you. Could you try to describe what you came up with so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code sample doesn't appear to be a serious attempt to have solved the problem, so this is a "gimme teh codez" question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your character conversion table is stored in a `Map<Character, Character>`, this should do it:

```
Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
StringBuffer result = str.chars()
    .mapToObj(i -> map.get((char)i) == null ? String.valueOf((char) i)
            : String.valueOf((char) map.get((char)i)))
    .collect(Collectors.reducing(new StringBuffer(), StringBuffer::new, StringBuffer::append));
```

This code gets an `IntStream` representing the individual `char` from your `String` using the `String#chars` method. It then runs through each of them, looking them up in the map and replacing them if it needs to, and finally it performs a mutating reduction using the mutable `StringBuffer` class. If you need the result as a `String`, simply invoke its `toString` method.